# ASP.NET C# & Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am making the transition from DataTableAdapters in MSVS to creating Stored Procedures in MS SQL Server.

This is what I have so far.

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var conString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString(); 
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getAdministrators", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userNameTB.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passwordTB.Text;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to grab all the rows/columns and store them in a DataSet and use the values returned at my will for whatever I wish. What am I missing to accomplish this. Or if someone has an article that could help as well?

I updated the code to use `using`.

I think the code is slowly getting there...

Comment: Note: you should probably get into the habit of using `using` for things like `SqlCommand`, `SqlConnection`, etc

Comment: definetely. "open late, close early". also - are you sure those fields are `VarChar` and not `NVarChar`?

Comment: Right in the beginning of the On_Click I  throw a using in there? Any code snippets or articles?

Comment: I edited the code above to use USING

Comment: just a suggestion, but it is very confusing when you keep editing you original answer based on the feedback you get...makes the flow of the questions and answers very difficult to follow/understand...maybe post a reply instead so someone down the road reading the question can make sense of the answers and comments that were posted? When you finally are done, your code snippet will work and nobody will understand why anyone was making suggestions to change it...

Comment: Ah good point, my bad. I didn't think about it. I can put back up the original posted code when i get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet works:

```
    public static DataSet GetAll(int id)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Database.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ContactGetAll", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(dsData);
                    return dsData;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the code firing when a button is clicked though, so what should I replace RETURN with?

Comment: don't return anything, change my function declaration to your submit_click event declaration and drop the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I would expect the following to work:

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
  ds.Tables[0].Load(reader);
}
```

(assuming you want to populate the zeroth table)

Comment: I want to return everything into a nice organized set and use the least amount of code to reference it.

Comment: @Bry4n a fine aim - I don't understand that that means in terms of my reply, though.

Comment: I don't know. I probably don't know the proper question to ask. I never worked with SPs in C# I mainly use ColdFusion at work which is very different. Like do i use DataSets and a ExecuteReader? Which needs to be in or out of the connection? ha

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx

I guess you missed `cmd.ExecuteReader`